# Know if Fields/Properties of an object are "simple/primitive" types or other objects?

Tags: c#, properties, field

I got the following code that generate a DLL (sample exemple) :

```
public class PluginClass
{
    private string _MyString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get { return _MyString; }
        set
        {
            _MyString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyString");
        }
    }

    public int MyInt;

    public SpeedGenerator SpeedGenerator1 = new SpeedGenerator();

    public GaugeValueGenerator GaugeValueGenerator1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PluginClass()
    {
        GaugeValueGenerator1 = new GaugeValueGenerator();
    }
}
```

As you can see I got 4 fields/properties.

1 primitive field (primitive is int/string/bool/etcetc...) : MyInt
1 primitive property : MyString
1 object field : SpeedGenerator1
1 object property : GaugeValueGenerator1

When Im parsing my DLL I got to do some code that is in the function : WriteProperty

```
var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
var props = type.GetProperties();

foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
{
    WriteProperty(field.FieldType, field.Name, XXX);
}

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    WriteProperty(prop.PropertyType, prop.Name, XXX);
}
```

My question is on XXX that is a boolean that indicate if my field/property is "primitive". So it must be set to false if it is an object.
I fell like I tried quite everything but I can't resolve it...
Any help will be very appreciate !

(My idea was to call

```
var props = propertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

and consider that it should be empty for simple/primitive types ! But no... for example on String, this return the properties Chars (char[]) and Length (int)...)

(nb : Of course I don't wanna do a string operation on field/property.Name/FullName... something like

```
if ((propertyType.FullName).Contains("System."))
```

would be very very sucky... and inaccurate)

Comment: You're going to have to define what you mean by "primitive". Do you want to treat `string` as a primitive, even though it's a reference type? Do you consider `DateTime` to be a primitive? What about `Guid`, or `enum`s, or `System.Object`?

Comment: Answered in the comments of the top rated answer (at the moment)

Comment: Checking for "System" in the fullname is not really failsafe either. Nothing stops somebody from creating a class with it's fullname containing "System." even if its not recommended at all.

Comment: Yeah I agree, thats why I REALLY want to avoid this solution !

Comment: You still haven't clearly defined what you mean by "primitive" (and didn't answer a single one of the questions in my comment above). You have a general idea of what you want, but unless you can specify it precisely, you won't be able to implement it in code.

Comment: Hum yeah, but my point was that there should be "something" that clearly identify that we are dealing with an object define by the user. That's what I'd call "not primitive" :o You seem to be right but it's kinda surprising that you got nothing that can instantly tell you if your property/field is from the C#-core definition or if it's like an exotic type defined by the user :(

Comment: This is not clear enough ? (The difference between types from C# and the ones define by users/someone else)

Comment: So you would consider, say, [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) or [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) to be primitive types, because they're defined by the .NET library rather than user code? Or if you're just talking about mscorlib, then how about [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx)? There are a lot of *Microsoft-authored* types that are far from *primitive.*

Comment: With the things I have to do, yes, they are primitive type. I didnt say that thet are simple or "small" object (with 1 or few properties) but they are primitive as they are define by microsoft/.NET (for me !)

Comment: @Guillaume Slashy: Guillaume I've been thinking that a "hack" to work around your problem is to store the `PublicKeyToken` of one .NET `Assembly` and then simply check for any given `Type` if the `PublicKeyToken` of the defining `Assembly` matches the original. You should double check  my assumption but it stands to reason that all .NET assemblies, given a .NET version, should share the same PublicKeyToken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use [`IsPrimitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) of the `Type` class?

```
XXX = field.FiledType.IsPrimitive
```

**EDIT:** You will have to treat `string` as a special case as `IsPrimitive` will not return `true`.

**EDIT 2:** The problem you are having is that you are trying to marry two *primitve* definitions wich don't match. Being that the case I can only see two options:

1. Make both definitions match which obviously you can't do changing the CLR type system and probably can't do either changing the framework you are using.
2. Make some *hack* that "marries" both definitions. I see no other way around hardcoding the specific exceptions that don't match one of the two definitions of *primitve* types.

Comment: Yeah, edit to my answer. Just factor out a helper method isPrimitve(Type t) which checks if it is a primitive or `string`. You haveto hard code the few exceptions you know you might run into (decimal, DateTime, etc) as they are not really primitves.

Comment: Ok with the edit but the LukeH's answer seems to indicate that strings are not the only exception... :( If there are a lot of exception, this is not that good to treat all of them separately :(

Comment: It is not, but unless somebody else comes up with something I think there is no general way around your problem.

Comment: Hum yeah, but my point was that there should be "something" that clearly identify that we are dealing with an object define by the user. That's what I'd call "not primitive" :o You seem to be right but it's kinda surprising that you got nothing that can instantly tell you if your property/field is from the C#-core definition or if it's like an exotic type defined by the user :(

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy That's because most types in the framework are just plain C# code with perhaps a few `InternallCall` methods.

Comment: @Guillaume Slashy: Guillaume I've been thinking that a "hack" to work around your problem is to store the PublicKeyToken of one .NET Assembly and then simply check for any given Type if the PublicKeyToken of the defining Assembly matches the original. You should double check my assumption but it stands to reason that all .NET assemblies, given a .NET version, should share the same PublicKeyToken. – InBetween 6 mins ago

Answer (score 6):

This should do it.

```
 public static bool IsPrimate(this object obj)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            typeof (Enum),
            typeof (String),
            typeof (Char),
            typeof (Guid),
            typeof (Boolean),
            typeof (Byte),
            typeof (Int16),
            typeof (Int32),
            typeof (Int64),
            typeof (Single),
            typeof (Double),
            typeof (Decimal),
            typeof (SByte),
            typeof (UInt16),
            typeof (UInt32),
            typeof (UInt64),
            typeof (DateTime),
            typeof (DateTimeOffset),
            typeof (TimeSpan),
        }.Any(oo => oo.IsInstanceOfType(obj));
    }
```

Comment: I just noticed this says, `IsPrimate`, not `IsPrimitive`.

Comment: @Ermish i know - that's a joke.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `field.FieldType.IsPrimitive` and `prop.PropertyType.IsPrimitive`, but you're going to be disappointed if you're expecting `string`, `decimal` etc to be considered primitives.

Why not create your own set of types that *you* consider to be primitives and check against that?

```
WriteProperty(f.FieldType, f.Name, yourPrimitives.Contains(f.FieldType));

// ...

WriteProperty(p.PropertyType, p.Name, yourPrimitives.Contains(p.PropertyType));

// ...

private static readonly HashSet<Type> yourPrimitives = new HashSet<Type>
    {
        typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(decimal)    // etc
    };
```

Another option would be to use [`GetTypeCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx) and then check that the result isn't [`TypeCode.Object`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx), [`TypeCode.DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode.aspx) etc. It really depends on *exactly* what your requirements are, and *exactly* what *you* consider to be a primitive type.

Comment: Yeah, and I got to handle Strings :(